# Google App Engine with Android - testing endpoints on real device

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've been following the tutorial in [Creating an Endpoints Backend from an Android Project](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-create-fromandroid). Everything is being compiled and looks promising. The backend is up.

I changed `CloudEndpointUtils#LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN` to `true`. But when I try to test the app on a real device (not emulator) I'm failing on:

`java.net.SocketException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8888) after 20000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)`

So I looked at `CloudEndpointUtils` and saw that setting `LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN` to `true` makes the app look for DevAppServer in **`http://10.0.2.2:8888`**, which is the emulator virtual router.

But I'm not using the emulator. So I tried to change the constant holding this url to **`http://127.0.0.1:8888/`** but still no luck. I'm now failing on:

`java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 8888) after 20000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)`

I thought it might be because my PC is behind a firewall, so I disabled it, but still nothing.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: since the device and server are on the same wifi network, i tried one more thing which is to use the server's ip on the network, and now im getting -

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.0.1 (port 8888) after 20000ms

Comment: try changing host ip to 0.0.0.0 means it will accept from anywhere. Then point to your computer IP.

Comment: i've added --address=*server_ip* argument to the App Engine server's Run configuration (in Eclipse). now when i open 'http://server_ip/8888' from the connected device's browser i finally see the "Cloud Endpoints Starter Template" page but... there is also en error 'Could not fetch URL: http://127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/spi/', which means somewhere the server still looks on localhost. i get the same error also when i call one of my endpoints from the app.

Comment: @Faisal where should i change the host ip ?

Comment: when starting the server probably that --address=0.0.0.0 so it's accessible from anywhere although the main problem seems to be that your generated library is pointing to localhost, probably change that too when debugging, I can't find where I read that I think it maybe a parameter.

Comment: @Faisal please try to remember man. i've been banging my head with this for hours.

Comment: add the --address="0.0.0.0" instead of server IP is what I meant on eclipse appengine server. 127.0.0.1 would fail to connect to itself when you specify a specific server. So 0.0.0.0 means accept from anywhere. I don't have any idea on what else if this don't work.

Comment: it worked !!!! you are the king.

Comment: cool! I added it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the

```
--address="0.0.0.0"
```

as the app engine server address parameter 
to accept from all incoming connections.

Comment: Can you please explain where to add this? What should be the value of `LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL_FOR_ANDROID`?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to do this in Android Studio, set httpAddress as follows in your build.gradle

```
appengine {

  ...

  httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Nice.  I spent a lot of time trying to find the answer to this.

Answer (score 7):

To accomplish this

1. Put LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL_FOR_ANDROID = your IP address (this is in your android App)
2. Right click on App-Engine project -> Run-> Run  Configurations -> Web Application(left bar) -> your app-engine project.

2.(Contniued) Go to Arugments -> add  exactly like this

--address=0.0.0.0 --port=.......

*to get your ip address, go to cmd -> ipconfig -> add (IPV4 address with port number) in step 1

**important note:** Please change this everytime in case you are accessing internet from dongle or some dynamic IP internet service

Thankyou ... this works perfectly

Answer (score 6):

There are many answers here but I've found them messy or uncomplete. To run the local server on your computer and test it with a *real* device do this:

1) Add `httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"` to the `appengine` block in your `build.gradle` file of the backend (Google Cloud Endpoint) module, like this:

```
appengine {
    ...
    httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
}
```

According to a comment on the question this means that 'will accept from anywhere'.

2) Run your backend module locally (ie. start the web server). This is trivial: select the backend configuration on the drop-down menu and press the green button. You can [find more detailed instructions here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints).

You should now be able to open a browser (on your computer) and navigate to `http://localhost:8080/` and see a webpage with 'Hello, Endpoints!' and many other stuff.

3) Find your computer's IP address (on a Mac go to System Preferences -> Network) and then set it as the root url in your Android app code, like this:

```
MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(
                            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                            new AndroidJsonFactory(), 
                            null
).setRootUrl("http://192.168.1.36:8080/_ah/api/")
```

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

When locally testing Google cloud endpoints from none localhost address --address="0.0.0.0"  setting might not be sufficient.

My Endpoints were giving 404 Not Found error when accessing from non localhost. I resolved it by including *path* parameter in [API decoration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#defining_an_api_method_endpointsmethod).

My API annotation looked like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name="saveResponse", httpMethod = "post", path="saveResponse)
public Response saveResponse(@Named("answerString") String responseString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow  the 2. point post  by user248187
          2.(Contniued) Go to Arugments -> add exactly like this
              --address=0.0.0.0 --port=.......

Now, On the client android code you need change the request IP (RootURL) of your services to local IP.  You can do that by use builder.setRootUrl(). It  is good  that  you add  a flat for outomatice it on you android client, then it can switch between local and deployed app-engiene quickly. Such as:

```
//........................

private boolean mFlatLocalHostServer=true;  
private static final String LOCAL_IP = "192.168.1.11"; //Ip debug server
public static final String  LOCAL_SERVER_IP = "http://"+LOCAL_IP+":8888/_ah/api";
//......................
Mydataendpoint.Builder builder = new Mydataendpoint.Builder(
                                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                                new GsonFactory(),
                                        mCredential); 

//request the  service to local ip 
if(mFlatLocalHostServer){
         builder.setRootUrl(LOCAL_SERVER_IP); 
}

Mydataendpoint service =  builder.build();
response=service.insertMyData(mydata).execute();
```

Answer (score -2):

Address **10.0.2.2** is for accessing localhost using the emulator, to access localhost using a real device, use the following steps

-open your commandline (cmd) run ipconfig.
-Get the ipaddress of your computer and replace **10.0.2.2**   with it,
-Build and run on your device.

**Hope this helps someone**