# Using real device to test App Engine Connected Android app on local server

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, sockets

I am following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae to test my application locally. In step 6 instead of using an emulator, I use a real device. I get the following error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8888) after 20000ms
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:964)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

Any ideas how I may fix this? I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971954/google-app-engine-with-android-testing-endpoints-on-real-device) but have no idea how to implement their solution (if there is one). I am using eclipse juno with the app-engine plugin.

I right clicked on my project and when to Run Config to see if there is something there that I can change, I am not sure what I would change or add.

**Update**

Having changed to 0.0.0.0, what do I set LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL to in android? I try pretty much all of the responses in the linked post, but I am still getting the same error. So I figure I must need to make a change in android itself.

Actually I sometimes get the error log (after the 0.0.0.0 change)

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8080) after 20000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
 java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8080) after 20000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:224)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:964)
    at  at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:224)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

Comment: Having changed to 0.0.0.0, what do I set `LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL` to? in android I mean.